# Codeigniter SQL Injection

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-injection

I have this code on my controller:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = " . $this->input->get('foo'); 
$foo = $this->db->query($sql);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($foo->result());
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

I've noticed that if I use this URL:
www.site.com?foo=1 OR 1 = 1
all data of the user table is shown:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [email] => aaa@gmail.com
        [password] => aaa
    )
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [email] => bbb@gmail.com
        [password] => bbb
    )
[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [email] => ccc@gmail.com
        [password] => ccc
    )
)
```

Is it possible to run another query that returns the data from the user_phone table?

**Tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `user_phone` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `number` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Data:**

```
INSERT  INTO `user`(`email`,`password`) VALUES ('aaa@gmail.com','aaa');
INSERT  INTO `user`(`email`,`password`) VALUES ('bbb@gmail.com','bbb');
INSERT  INTO `user`(`email`,`password`) VALUES ('ccc@gmail.com','ccc');

INSERT  INTO `user_phone`(`id_user`,`number`) VALUES ('1','911911911');
INSERT  INTO `user_phone`(`id_user`,`number`) VALUES ('1','922922922');
INSERT  INTO `user_phone`(`id_user`,`number`) VALUES ('2','955955955');
INSERT  INTO `user_phone`(`id_user`,`number`) VALUES ('3','711711711');
```

Thks

**EDIT:**
I'm aware of the existing mechanisms to prevent this from happening.
My question is if it's possible, and how, can I get data from other tables.

Comment: use `real_escape_string` or something similar to prevent injection. never trust user input

Comment: Can you use parameter binding instead of directly concatenating values like that?  You're essentially *executing user input as code*.

Comment: are you asking for the injection string? in short, yes, it is possible to run a query that will output data from any and all tables/databases that the current mysql user has access to, and more

Comment: Hi guys! Thks for the replies. I'm aware of the functions/methods that can prevent this from happening. My question is if it's possible, with this code, return data from other tables. Thks!

Comment: you want data from table users and user phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's going to be like this.

```
www.site.com?foo=1 OR 1 = 1 union select * from user_phone where user_phone.id_user = user.id
```

Comment: Hi volkinc! It fails on the user.id  (Unknown column 'user.id' in 'where clause') but I get the picture. Thks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

CI comes with functions to escape variables for exactly this reason.

```
$foo = $this->input->get('foo');
$foo = $this->db->escape($foo);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = {$foo}"; 
$foo = $this->db->query($sql);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($foo->result());
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

Comment: Hi Jim. I'm aware of the escape method. My question is if it's possible with this code return data from other tables.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to bind your query using something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ? AND name = ?"; 
$foo = $this->db->query($sql, array('foo', 'bar'));
```

As for getting data from other tables, you'd just need to construct a more elaborate sql query

Answer (score 0):

You asked about querying data from 2 tables, to query 2 related tables you can use join. In your example user and user_phone are related. You perform sql queries with join like demo below. The user primary_key is the glue in user_phone table.
1 - select * 
2 - pass the id we want to retrieve
3 - from which table
4 - perform a join or multiple joins 
5 - get the result
try this

```
$this -> db -> select('*');
$this -> db -> where('id' => '1');
$this -> db -> from('user');
$this -> db -> join('user_phone', 'user_phone.id_user = user.id');
$query = $this -> db -> get();
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer? An answer is much more useful if it explains what is being done so that its techniques can be applied to other situations.

Comment: right, I was in a  bit of a rush, I added info to explain what the statement does and how it is done. Thanks for pointing that out though :).

Comment: Hi mdamia. Thk you for the reply. Basically, my question was how to join tables using **SQL Injection**, not using code.